# How can I play Minecraft through a proxy server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

There are many people that are forced to use a proxy, be it students in shared accommodation or school staff. Following the blog of [The Minecraft Teacher](http://minecraftteacher.net/) I've realised that Minecraft *could* be used for educational purposes, but most schools have a proxy.

I've so far found that moving the `minecraft.exe` into the `%appdata%/bin` folder and creating a batch file with this in *should* work:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=hostURL -Dhttp.proxyPort=hostPort -Xmx800m -jar Minecraft.exe
```

... although I've so far been unable to get this to work.

Comment: [assuming you are a member of faculty] If you're using it for educational purposes, surely your IT will be able to adjust the proxy rules to allow for it?

Comment: I am the schools ICT technician. The proxy is very strict and to get it changed would take a very, very long time.

Comment: i recommend that you ask on superuser/serverfault. they have much more experience in handling such cases where making changes to network settings and handling of ports, etc.

Comment: You did replace the hostURL and hostPort values with the actual IP and port of your proxy right?

Comment: The short answer, if you have a very restrictive firewall then there may not be any way to get minecraft to work sort aside from some ugly Tunnel/VPN hacks that may get you fired, if they are found.  Find someone with authority, perhaps a Superintendent, Principal, head of Curriculum and have them help you convince the people responsible for the firewall to allow this.

Comment: @Zoredache, yes, I did. Also it looks like the VPN way is the only way so I'll have to see how much noise is needed.

Comment: BTW, do you know what kind of proxy you are using?  Does it have different policies depending on who is logged in?  If so, then your proxy probably requires authentication, and I doubt Minecraft supports that directly.

Comment: @Zoredache not sure but there is some authentication required..I think I'll write this one off (or see if Notch brings in proxy support)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As things currently stand, there is no way of playing Minecraft, Vanilla (i.e. no mods or extra software), through a proxy. This may change within time and if it does I will update the answer.

Comment: this is false. I just downloaded the game and I am playing through a proxy right now

Comment: @nosklo, this question (and answer) was posted over *a year and a half ago* so the answer would have likely changed. If you would like to answer I would gladly move the tick from my answer to yours, provided the solution work.

Comment: @tombull89 Dutch's answer seems to work. Maybe you could consider accepting it.

Answer (score 12):

To be able to play not just the HTTP proxy needs to be added, but also the HTTPS, because authenticating is going through that.

The proper batch file should look like this:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyURL -Dhttp.proxyPort=proxyPORT -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyURL -Dhttps.proxyPort=proxyPORT -Xmx800m -jar Minecraft.exe
```

I put the batch file next to my Minecraft.exe and started with this.
Works like a charm ;)

Comment: You could also look into Socks4/5 proxies. They are much faster.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to work. Proxy settings are totally ignored. Nothing logged by proxy.

Answer (score 5):

If you have sufficient control over the server, I'd suggest using something like [n2n](http://www.ntop.org/n2n/), which is an awesomely simple (though command line argument heavy, and gui-less) VPN system.

[PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) is a very cool ssh client for all platforms, and while the tunneling configuration is a bit wonky, you can essentially remap the server's port to a local port (the command would be ssh -L:localhost:  though working through the gui would be a bit harder.) When you've got that set up, you can type localhost: into Minecraft and connect to the server. Note that you need ssh access to the server for this to work, similar to the solution.

Those are all the solutions I can think of now, though previous posters have suggested other VPNs you might want to look in to.

Answer (score 4):

I have wanted to do the same thing and by combining the answers on this page along with the answers on another page, I have a solution that is working for me.  All the commands that you'll need (create a batch file and put it in the same directory that the `minecraft.exe` file is in) are:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=443 -DsocksProxyHost=localhost -DsocksProxyPort=1080 -Xmx800m -jar Minecraft.exe
```

The extra part (on top of what [Dutch suggests](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/26631/1980)) is the forwarding of the SOCKS port as well.  With all this in a batch file and with my SSH proxy running through [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), I was able to connect to multiplayer servers without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your best shot would be to set up your own proxy.

I do not know if you can configure an SSH connection to a PC of yours. But SSH enable you to tunnel connections via the SSH one.

So if your school does not allow the port you need, you'll have to "enable" it by your own means. (The best would be SSH cause you can set it up on 443 port that is use for HTTPS, so it is enabled in most proxies)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Comodo VPN](http://easy-vpn.comodo.com/) to play Minecraft with my friends and it works great, right out of the box.

We're students and our dorms each connect to the Internet via separate NATs, so we cannot establish connections directly between our machines. Because of that, even though SSH and proxies are possible, they weren't really practical since we needed an external server for them, so we decided to use a VPN software. Once the connection is established, traffic is routed directly between us, not using an external server, so the speed is great.

If you have the necessary privileges required to install software on the machines you're using, I'd recommend giving Comodo VPN a try (it's [free as in beer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_as_in_beer) by the way).

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/26631/73479) used to work for me, but recently stopped working, possibly due to a Minecraft update. Now I run Minecraft via [ProxyChains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/) ala

```
proxychains java -jar Minecraft.jar
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it gives me connection timed out.