# Run Minecraft with proxy on Linux

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux

I've seen the following thread:

[How can I play Minecraft through a proxy server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21848/how-can-i-play-minecraft-through-a-proxy-server)

But I'm running Linux and I don't have a Minecraft jar file. I only have a binary file that is under the /usr/bin directory that is a standard binary and won't work with Java. How can I proxy Minecraft on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

The new Minecraft launcher is not a Java app on Windows or Linux.

You will have to either use the old launcher (doesn't work with Microsoft Accounts, but I did create a private patch for that), or a launcher that supports proxies like, [MultiMC](https://multimc.org/) (I know I keep recommending it, but it fixes many problems with Mojang's launcher).

Simply find the proxy option in the settings.

Unfortunately, it doesn't apply to the game. I cannot test this as I don't have a proxy server, but you could try adding the arguments to the game's Java arguments.