# How can I play Minecraft through a SOCKS5 proxy server on Linux?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux, networking

The title explains most of it: I have been searching around regarding this question and have searched places like: [Run Minecraft with proxy on Linux](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392115/run-minecraft-with-proxy-on-linux),
[How can I play Minecraft through a proxy server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21848/how-can-i-play-minecraft-through-a-proxy-server)
and some Reddit posts, but I can't seem to find an answer. And yes I have tried changing the Java arguments that the game launched with but it seemed not to proxy my connection.

**My java arguments:**

```
-DsocksProxyHost=[127.0.0.1] -DsocksProxyPort=[2078] -Djava.net.socks.username=[] -Djava.net.socks.password=[]
```

⬆️
My proxy has no username or password, so I kept those blank.

Comment: Does [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1401585/how-to-force-all-linux-apps-to-use-socks-proxy) answer your question?

Comment: Not sure if it matters that this is for Linux.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I play Minecraft through a proxy server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21848/how-can-i-play-minecraft-through-a-proxy-server)

Comment: Different problem, different solution.

Answer (score 6):

[Your command is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242493/linux-unix-man-page-syntax-conventions); when you enter a command you do not keep the brackets.

Instead of:

```
-DsocksProxyHost=[127.0.0.1] -DsocksProxyPort=[2078] -Djava.net.socks.username=[] -Djava.net.socks.password=[]
```

Try:

```
-DsocksProxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DsocksProxyPort=2078 -Djava.net.socks.username="" -Djava.net.socks.password=""
```